# How to play a mp3 using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, mp3

I have a directory on my website with several mp3's.
I dynamically create a list of them in the website using php.

I also have a drag and drop function associated to them and I can select a list of those mp3 to play.

Now, giving that list, how can I click on a button (Play) and make the website play the first mp3 of the list? (I also know where the music is on the website)

Comment: In modern browsers, you could use [HTML5's `<audio>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_audio_and_video_in_Firefox)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you want a version that works for old browsers, I have made this library:

```
// source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11331200/4298200
function Sound(source, volume, loop)
{
    this.source = source;
    this.volume = volume;
    this.loop = loop;
    var son;
    this.son = son;
    this.finish = false;
    this.stop = function()
    {
        document.body.removeChild(this.son);
    }
    this.start = function()
    {
        if (this.finish) return false;
        this.son = document.createElement("embed");
        this.son.setAttribute("src", this.source);
        this.son.setAttribute("hidden", "true");
        this.son.setAttribute("volume", this.volume);
        this.son.setAttribute("autostart", "true");
        this.son.setAttribute("loop", this.loop);
        document.body.appendChild(this.son);
    }
    this.remove = function()
    {
        document.body.removeChild(this.son);
        this.finish = true;
    }
    this.init = function(volume, loop)
    {
        this.finish = false;
        this.volume = volume;
        this.loop = loop;
    }
}
```

Documentation:

`Sound` takes three arguments. The `source` url of the sound, the `volume` (from `0` to `100`), and the `loop` (`true` to loop, `false` not to loop).
`stop` allow to `start` after (contrary to `remove`).
`init` re-set the argument volume and loop.

Example:

```
var foo = new Sound("url", 100, true);
foo.start();
foo.stop();
foo.start();
foo.init(100, false);
foo.remove();
//Here you you cannot start foo any more
```

Comment: is it possible to know when a music ends?

Comment: Do you have the length of the music?

Comment: browsers support for simple audio: http://caniuse.com/#search=audio

Comment: Does it need a specific audio format? Doesn't work with MP3s here..

Answer (score 131):

```js
new Audio('<url>').play()
```

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement)

Comment: Full documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement

Comment: Worked as Charm... without any complexity

Comment: What if I want to play several songs? Won't issuing a `new Audio` for each one cause a memory leak?

Comment: @Rodrigo probably, but it's another question. The `<audio>` tag works (in this case) the same as an `<img>` tag; you can update the `src` property to change the file for the element.

Comment: In one of my applications I use only 3 different sounds. So at the page load I declare a disctionary of three "new Audio" and run each of them based on specific cases.

Answer (score 10):

You will probably want to use the new HTML5 `audio` element to create an `Audio` object, load the mp3, and play it.

Due to browser inconsistencies, this sample code is a bit lengthly, but it should suit your needs with a bit of tweaking.

```
//Create the audio tag
var soundFile = document.createElement("audio");
soundFile.preload = "auto";

//Load the sound file (using a source element for expandability)
var src = document.createElement("source");
src.src = fileName + ".mp3";
soundFile.appendChild(src);

//Load the audio tag
//It auto plays as a fallback
soundFile.load();
soundFile.volume = 0.000000;
soundFile.play();

//Plays the sound
function play() {
   //Set the current time for the audio file to the beginning
   soundFile.currentTime = 0.01;
   soundFile.volume = volume;

   //Due to a bug in Firefox, the audio needs to be played after a delay
   setTimeout(function(){soundFile.play();},1);
}
```

Edit:

To add Flash support, you would append an `object` element inside the `audio` tag.

Comment: I know this answer is 4 years old.  But of the list of them here, this is the best one.  I tweaked it a bit to serve my purposes.  But it works on everything. Even IE.  And that's really saying something.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`<audio>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/audio) HTML5 tag to play audio using JavaScript.

But this is not cross-browser solution. It supported only in modern browsers. For cross-browser compatibility you probably need to use Flash for that (for example [jPlayer](http://www.jplayer.org/)).

Browsers compatibility table is provided at link I mentioned above.

Comment: Can you provide a flash example?

Comment: @aF. you can see a lot of demos here: http://jplayer.org/latest/demos/ . jPlayer is opensource and released under GPL and MIT licenses.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [SoundManager 2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/): it will transparently handle the `<audio>` tag wherever it's supported, and use Flash wherever it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the browser supports MP3 playback and is fairly new to support newer JavaScript features, I would suggest taking a look at [jPlayer](http://www.jplayer.org/).
You can see a short demo [tutorial](http://www.jplayer.org/latest/demo-01-supplied-mp3/) on how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery plugin for audio mp3 player http://www.jplayer.org/0.2.1/demos/

Answer (score -1):

Enjoy it ;)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Play my music....</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>
        <a id="PlayLink" href="http://www.moderntalking.ru/real/music/Modern_Talking-You_Can_Win(DEMO).mp3" onclick="pplayMusic(this, 'music_select');">U Can Win</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a id="A1" href="http://www.moderntalking.ru/real/music/Modern_Talking-Brother_Louie(DEMO).mp3" onclick="pplayMusic(this, 'music_select');">Brother Louie</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mediaplayer.yahoo.com/js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```