# Click in icon play to start sound, then click stop icon to stop sound

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a link with icon play, when I click in this icon I want to start play a sound. And in the moment that the sound starts I want to show a stop icon replacing the play icon.

I am trying to do this with this code below, but [isn´t](http://jsfiddle.net/s8v3sueq/3/) working:

`jquery:`

```
$(function(){
    function play() {
        var audio = document.getElementById('audio1');
        if (audio.paused) {
            audio.play();
        }else{
            audio.pause();
            audio.currentTime = 0
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to add!

Comment: There are some existing [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11330917/2679750) out there, have you tried browsing at any of those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you need?

I made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/boqs38pf/

HTML:

```
<audio id="audio1" src="http://www.freesfx.co.uk/rx2/mp3s/10/11771_1410942915.mp3"></audio>

<a id="play"  href="#" onClick="play()"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></a>
<a id="stop" href="#" onClick="play()"><i class="fa fa-stop"></i></a>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var audioElement = document.getElementById('audio1');
    $('#stop').hide();

    $('#play').click(function() {
        $('#play').hide();
        $('#stop').show();
        audioElement.play();
    });


    $('#stop').click(function() {
        $('#play').show();
        $('#stop').hide();
        audioElement.pause();
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, thanks! By the way do you know how to put this more dinamic? For example if I have more than 1 sound, instead of have this:   var audioElement = document.getElementById('audio1');, receive any audio element?

Answer (score 1):

To make it more dynamic for multiple audio files what you would want to do is assign each button an id with a number that would match the id of the song you want it to control. After that you need to add to the .click function some code that will get the id of the button clicked and and play the song with the relevant Id.

```
$('.play').click(function(){
        var i = $(this).attr('id');
        var c = parseInt(i); 
        var g = '#idofsong' + c; 
        g.play();
    });
```

Edit: here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xd4rL0pj/1/)

Also you want to use `var c = i.replace(/[A-Za-z$-]/g, "");` instead of parseInt if the id contains letters