# Decode Base 64 audio file Mp3 into playable Mp3

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, phonegap-plugins, html5-audio

I am converting the audio MP3 file and storing it as base64 in database using WEB API, now I am fetching the base64 file using ajax and I am getting the base64, the problem is how can I convert the base64 file back to mp3 file and play it using JavaScript.

This if for demo I am using input file, I am getting base64 file from server

```html
<input type='file' onchange='openFile(event)' id="EdituserProfileImage">
```

```js
var fileName;
var filetype;
var filesize;
var VoiceBase64;
var openFile = function (event) {
    var input = event.target;
    fileName = input.files[0].name;
    filetype = input.files[0].type;
    filesize = input.files[0].size;
    console.log(input);
    console.log(fileName);
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (evt) {
        var voiceInBinay = evt.target.result;
        VoiceBase64 = btoa(voiceInBinay);
        contvertBase64toBinaray(VoiceBase64);
    };
    reader.readAsBinaryString(input.files[0]);
};
```

This function "contvertBase64toBinaray" using for converting base64 to Binary, I have binary file, need to save as mp3 from this below binary

```js
function contvertBase64toBinaray(VoiceBase64) {
    var audiofile = atob(VoiceBase64)
};
```

Comment: I don't get the link between your code and your question. If you have a dataURI coming from your database, the dataURI you have is already a representation of the full mp3 file. You can directly add this as the source (`src`) of an `<audio>` element and play it as is. If you are trying to read a file from an input element, use the `readAsDataURL` method of the FileReader and apply what I've just said.

Comment: and if you actually have a binary string, you just have to add the dataURI header  `'data:audio/mp3;base64,'` to the `btoa()`of your result (`var dataURI = 'data:audio/mp3;base64,'+btoa(binaryString)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `window.atob` function to decode your base 64 data.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330917/how-to-play-a-mp3-using-javascript) question shows you how you can play the mp3 in JS.

Comment: ,thx, i converted using window.atob i am getting binary data, how i can covert back to Mp3,so i can play the file and save it.

Comment: The data you have now in the buffer is real mp3 data. Use the link in my answer to create the player and use the data you have as a datauri in src.

Comment: i want to save in local folder has mp3 file with name,i have binary data, want to play it using JavaScript,i am using File Api