# How can i stop page to redirects to the file path in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html

While creating a page for word of the day, if I click on volume up icon I am able to listen to the word of the day but not in the same page, it redirects me to the path and I have to click on play button to listen to this audio file.

here's my code

```
   <div class="word-and-pronunciation">
        <a href="audio (1).mp3" tabindex="0">
            <h2 class="word-l-hover">jocose</h2>
        </a>                
        <a class="play-pron converted" data-lang="en_us" data-file="jocose" data-dir="j" href="javascript:void(0)" title="How to pronounce jocose(audio)" tabindex="0">play 
          <span class="play-box">.</span>
        </a>
   </div>
```

Comment: you can try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18274061/html-5-audio-tag-multiple-files

Comment: this is not what i want... i have page for WORD OF THE DAY... where i m inserting Difficult Word on daily Basis... Next to that Word i have Volume-Up Icon by clicking on which i have audio file which is saved in my folder path, end user will be able to hear that ... but it redirects me to that audio file path, i want this audio to be played on the same page, if i click on Volume-Up Button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the HTML5 audio tag, more details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio)

**this is a sample code from the link above**

`<figure>
    <figcaption>Listen to the T-Rex:</figcaption>
    <audio
        controls
        src="/media/examples/t-rex-roar.mp3">
            Your browser does not support the
            <code>audio</code> element.
    </audio>
</figure>`

Comment: Thanks, happy to help

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is just a link to file. Try to use a simple [HTML 5 audio](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp).

Other ways you could find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330917/how-to-play-a-mp3-using-javascript).